# Android webkitSpeechRecognition .isFinal variable not showing correct value

Tags: javascript, android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, webkitspeechrecognition

I'm attempting to do some voice recognition stuff on mobile. Here's some code..

```
var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();

recognition.onresult = function (e) {
  //This is called every time the Speech Recognition hears you speak.
  //You may say "How's it going today", the recognition will try to 
  //interpret what you're saying while you're speaking. For example, while
  //you're speaking it may go.. "house" "how's it going" "how's it going today"
  //as it interprets it returns an object that contains properties, one of
  //which is "e.results[i].isFinal" where "i" is an array of returned objects.
  //In this case the object with a transcript of "house" would have a 
  //"e.results[i].isFinal" value of false. Where as the object with a transcript 
  //of "how's it going today" would have a "e.results[i].isFinal" value of 
  //true.. Because this is the FINAL INTERPRETATION of this particular transcript.

  //HOWEVER.. The problem I'm having is that when using a mobile device, the "e.results[i].isFinal" always
  //has a value of true, even when it's not the final interpretation. It works correctly on desktop however. Both are using Chrome. 

  if(e.results[e.results.length-1].isFinal){
      var finalTranscript = '';
      for(i=0;i<e.results.length;i++){
          finalTranscript += e.results[i][0].transcript;
      }
      console.log(finalTranscript);
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = finalTranscript;
  }
}
```

I'm just wondering if someone else has had this problem, as well as any insight on how to get around this problem.
I have an example on my website.

https://jaymartmedia.com/example/speech.html

I added some debug info onto the page (so that i could "see" the console while on mobile. On desktop you'll notice "2: Final: false" and sometimes "2: Final: true". This is the value of "e.results[i].isFinal". On mobile it will always (or at least every time I've tried it on my phone) be "2: Final: true".

It's causing major problems, any insight will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Same here! I'm trying other browsers. Some of them won't even open my web app.
But most of them has the same error.
At iPhone Safari, it worked all fine!

Answer (score 0):

I could NOT find the direct solution.

But in my case, it solves the bug when I disable all intermediate results:

```
var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();

recognition.continuous = false
// or
recognition.interimResults = false
```